# Retreiving individual values from a column with a list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the twitter username, and the list of hashtags in a particular tweet. The hashtags column maybe a single tweet, a list of tweet or an empty tweet.

```
screenName      hashtags
realDonaldTrump c("#1", "#2", "#2")
realDonaldTrump character(0)
realDonaldTrump #LaunchAmerica,
realDonaldTrump #GeorgeFloyd
realDonaldTrump c("#MinneapolisRiot", "#Coronavirus")
```

I want to get a list of individual hashtags against a username.

Comment: Do you have only one username? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the unique `hashtags` for each `screenName` by unlisting them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(screenName) %>%
  summarise(hastags  = toString(unique(unlist(hashtags))))

# screenName      hashtags              
#  <chr>           <chr>                 
#1 realDonaldTrump #1, #2, #LaunchAmerica
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(screenName = c("realDonaldTrump", "realDonaldTrump", 
"realDonaldTrump"), hashtags = list(c("#1", "#2", "#2"), character(0), 
"#LaunchAmerica")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can `unnest` the 'hashtags' and then do a group by `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    unnest(c(hashtags)) %>%
    distinct %>% 
    group_by(screenName) %>%
    summarise(hashtags = toString(hashtags))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  screenName      hashtags              
#* <chr>           <chr>                 
#1 realDonaldTrump #1, #2, #LaunchAmerica
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(hashtags ~ screenName, unique(cbind(df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)),
    lengths(df$hashtags)), 'screenName', drop = FALSE],
     hashtags = unlist(df$hashtags))), toString)
#       screenName               hashtags
#1 realDonaldTrump #1, #2, #LaunchAmerica
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(screenName = c("realDonaldTrump", "realDonaldTrump", 
"realDonaldTrump"), hashtags = list(c("#1", "#2", "#2"), character(0), 
"#LaunchAmerica")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```